# How to use formal adjectives correctly?

Tags: adjectives, formality

My alma mater is officially called "Financial University", but periodically when I translate the text into google translate, it offers me the spelling "University of Finance" (The university is located in Russia)

I also noticed that my friends gave me business card where it was written "Marketing Department", while I also saw the spelling "Department of Marketing" on the Internet

What is the difference between these approaches? Adjective + noun or noun + of + noun

Comment: I note that the title of your university in Russian, is Финансовый Университет which translates as "**Financial** University" (**not** the genitive which would be финансов)The Wiki page - which one assumes is approved by the university is at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_University_under_the_Government_of_the_Russian_Federation. The short title is "Financial University".

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks for the note, I was just curious about the difference between these two forms of writing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attributive nouns vs. of-genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive) More specifically, ["X Department" versus "Department of X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505917/x-department-versus-department-of-x), but that was closed in favour of the more "general case" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universities named after places may choose to call themselves *University of Anytown* or *Anytown University.* Similarly with departments within a university - *Department of [subject]* or *Subject Department.* Both approaches are equally valid.

For this reason it's understandable that Google Translate sometimes renders the name of your institution as *University of Finance*, although this might sound as though 'Finance' were the town it is situated in.